# Python re.match include optional group that is None

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use re.compile in a for line loop. After the re.compile running a re.match on the lines. Using Regex101 I get the correct matches on the groups but running inside python it returns None for a group that has an empty string. What I am after is matching on groups even if they are empty.

The string to match on:

```
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
BE1                up          up          
Mg0/RSP0/CPU0/0    up          up          NNI to Cat2960x G1/0/1
Te0/0/0/3          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/1/0          down        down        Test L2VPN
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:LAB-9001-1#
```

The last group (description) should be optional and can either contain a description or be empty. This works in Regex101 and I have 4 groups on this filter:

```
^\s*(?:(?P<interface>[a-zA-Z0-9]\S+?))\s+(?:(?P<status>[up|admin\-down]\S+?))\s+(?:(?P<protocol>[up|admin\-down]\S+))\s+(?:(?P<description>(?<!^).*))
```

On the code I am using compile and match but if the description is blank it returns None, when I want it to return the first 3 groups and an empty string for  the 4th group (description).

```
for line in result.splitlines():
            line = line.rstrip()

            p1 = re.compile(r'^\s*(?:(?P<interface>[a-zA-Z0-9]\S+?))\s+(?:(?P<status>[up|admin\-down]\S+?))\s+(?:(?P<protocol>[up|admin\-down]\S+))\s+(?P<description>(?<!^).*)')
            m = p1.match(line).groups()
            print(m)
```

this will not match on anything that is blank for description. Is their a syntax to tell re.match to include empty groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you use contains character classes instead of grouping constructs (`[up|down]` does not match `up` or `down`, it matches `u`, `p`, `|`, `d`, `o`, `w` or `n`) and the last pattern part must match an obligatory space+any chars, but your `rstrip` the line and there is no space left to match.

The fixed regex looks like

```
^(?P<interface>[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*)\s+(?P<status>up|admin-down)\s+(?P<protocol>up|admin-down)(?:\s+(?P<description>.*))?
```

See the Regulex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?P<interface>[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*)` - Group "interface": an alphanumeric followed with any 0+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<status>up|admin-down)` - Group "status": `up` or `admin-down`
- `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<protocol>up|admin-down)` - Group "protocol": `up` or `admin-down`
- `(?:\s+(?P<description>.*))?` - an optional group:

  - `\s+` -  1+ whitespaces
  - `(?P<description>.*)` - Group "description": any 0+ chars other than line break as many as possible

In Python, you may use

```
import re
result = r"""Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
BE1                up          up          
Mg0/RSP0/CPU0/0    up          up          NNI to Cat2960x G1/0/1
Te0/0/0/3          admin-down  admin-down  
Gi0/0/1/0          down        down        Test L2VPN
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:LAB-9001-1#"""
p1 = re.compile(r'(?P<interface>[a-zA-Z0-9]\S*)\s+(?P<status>up|admin-down)\s+(?P<protocol>up|admin-down)(?:\s+(?P<description>.*))?')

for line in result.splitlines():
    line = line.rstrip()
    m = p1.match(line)
    if m:
        print(m.groups())
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/S2QbTN)

Note the `^` start of string anchor is not necessary if you use `re.match`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the demo as well as the explanation. Makes sense now with the rstrip.